# jenkins integration sonar error, Cannot run program "svn" Eorror

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

When I build my project with Jenkins, I got the error as below.
But if I remove sonar config, it's ok

## Log:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project bsp-cmts-provider: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/root/.jenkins/workspace/bsp-cmts"): error=2, No such file or directory -[Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.6:sonar (default-cli) on project bsp-cmts-provider: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/root/.jenkins/workspace/bsp-cmts"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/root/.jenkins/workspace/bsp-cmts"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.ExceptionHandling.handle(ExceptionHandling.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.bootstrap.RunnerBootstraper.execute(RunnerBootstraper.java:139)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/root/.jenkins/workspace/bsp-cmts"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:107)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.access$000(SvnBlameCommand.java:45)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand$1.call(SvnBlameCommand.java:91)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand$1.call(SvnBlameCommand.java:88)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "svn" (in directory "/root/.jenkins/workspace/bsp-cmts"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at org.sonar.api.utils.command.CommandExecutor.execute(CommandExecutor.java:76)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.execute(SvnBlameCommand.java:125)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.svn.SvnBlameCommand.blame(SvnBlameCommand.java:104)
    ... 7 more
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
... 10 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
SonarQube analysis completed: FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'SonarQube' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

*In fact, the directory name of "/root/.jenkins/workspace/bsp-cmts" has existed. 
I don't kwon why, Any body can help me deal with it?*

Comment: Post-build Actions config SonarQube

Comment: Looks like a dependency conflict to me.

Comment: does your jenkings run as "root" user? please don't run a CI server as root. Or is it using another user and does that user have access to that directory? It may just be folder permissions.

Comment: Please try to update to SQ SVN Plugin 1.1

Comment: Subversion Plug-in 2.51
SonarQube Plugin 2.21

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found the solution [sonarqubehispano](https://www.sonarqubehispano.org/questions/3506234/sonar-5.0-y-error-org.codehaus.mojosonar-maven-plugin2.4sonar)

[image]

Comment: what if u need the scm sensor to be enabled?